# isuess sync gradle for some old project from git

Tags: android-studio, build.gradle

> ERROR: Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1. Searched
>   in the following locations:
>       https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.4.1/gradle-3.4.1.pom
>       https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.4.1/gradle-3.4.1.jar
>   Required by:
>       project : Add Google Maven repository and sync project Open File Enable embedded Maven repository and sync project

**i have try to update distributionUrl**

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip
```

**and this my build gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.android.miwok"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation  "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$supportVersion"
    implementation  "com.android.support:support-v4:$supportVersion"
    implementation  "com.android.support:design:$supportVersion"
}
```

Comment: is internet working on you PC?

Comment: yes i have internet

Answer (score 0):

> well this is not best practice to do that, first of all, run that project in android studio and update the gradle,  follow one method from this link [Link](https://github.com/MagicMicky/FreemiumLibrary/wiki/Import-the-library-in-Android-Studio).